# How can I list specific attributes from xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I have a xml file that looks like this

```
<a>
<bb>
<c date="20110706" time="1:20" name1="john" name2="jen" nick1="johnny" nick2="jenny" />
<c date="20110806" time="2:20" name1="steven" name2="judith" nick1="steve" nick2="judy" />
</bb>
</a>
```

I currently have it set to grab the attributes value and set them as strings based on the value of one attribute. using this code

```
try {
    String name1 = mName1;

    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expr = String.format("//a/bb/c[@* = '%s']", name1);
    Node c = null;
    try {
        c = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expr, xml, XPathConstants.NODE);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is have all c lines listed one after the other in the format below using textviews, notice I do not want the nick1 and nick2 included.  I have been reading and testing for hours with arraylist and cant get the result I am looking for.  This is how I want all of the c nodes in the xml to be listed each in a textview.

Date:20110706 - Time:1:20 - HisName:john - HerName: jen

Date:20110806 - Time:2:20 - HisName:steven - HerName: judith

Also would would it be possible to have an imageview next to each name per line?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide, I have been trying to do this for hours with no luck its driving me crazy!

EDIT: by doing just "//a/bb/c" I get the first line of the xml with the information I want, but how do I move on to the next line, and so on?

Comment: by doing just "//a/bb/c" I get the first line of information I want, but how do I move on to the next, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a `returnType` of `XPathConstants.NODESET` as the second argument to `evaluate` and iterate the results:

```
final XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
final XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//a/bb/c");
final NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    final NamedNodeMap attrs = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();
    final Node dateNode = attrs.getNamedItem("date");
    System.out.println(dateNode.getNodeName() + ":" + dateNode.getNodeValue());
}
```

I've shown the output for the `date` attribute only, but the others should be obvious from this example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I ended up using dom and nodelist as I was able to find an example to work from.  Is there a benefit to using xpath as opposed to dom for this or vice versa?

Comment: Is there a simple way to combine my first method of searching for "name" and yours so that I can search the list for the name and have that displayed at the top of the nodelist and all the others below it?